# Tomcat8's "Silence" process using 100% CPU. What is this process?

Tags: tomcat, cpu-usage, tomcat8

After hitting some performance issues with one of our servers, I observed a Tomcat8 process called "Silence" using 100% continuously.
I tried to find information about it on Google, but searching for Tomcat and Silence doesn't show any meaningful results.

Here is what I've got in `top`:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                     
7362 tomcat8   20   0  239956   6688   1344 S 99.7  0.2   1679:33 Silence
```

Can someone help me understand what this "Silence" process is and how to fix this problem?
Of course there is nothing called "Silence" in our project, so I guess it is something Tomcat related.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Looks like this has been moved-over to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424288